# R studio logistic regression model - not able to make confusion matrix, also need to check accuracy of the model

Tags: r, logistic-regression

i have attached the code below, i am facing troble making confusion matric out of this, need to check kappa, accuracy etc as well.

please help me and any suggestion to make this code work better is appriciated.

`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)

setwd("/Users/samkit/Desktop/flame ug 2 /sem 2 /DATA MINING/final assignment final data")
getwd()

data <-read.csv("Telco-Customer-Churn.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
str(data)

# Convert intodummy variable

data$D_gender <- ifelse(data$gender == "Male", 1, 0)
data$D_Partner <- ifelse(data$Partner == "Yes", 1, 0)
data$D_dependents <- ifelse(data$Dependents == "Yes", 1, 0)
data$D_PhoneService <- ifelse(data$PhoneService == "Yes", 1, 0)
data$D_PaperlessBilling <- ifelse(data$PaperlessBilling == "Yes", 1, 0)

data$D_Multiplelines <- ifelse(data$PhoneService == 'Yes', 1, 0)
data$D_Churn <- ifelse(data$Churn== 'Yes',1,0)
head(data)
set.seed(123)
train_test_partitions <- createDataPartition(data$Churn, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train  <- data[train_test_partitions, ]
test <- data[-train_test_partitions, ]

# Use the dummy as the IV to predict "Survived"
model_1 = glm(Churn ~ ., data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(model_1)

model_2 = glm(D_Churn ~ SeniorCitizen+D_gender+D_Partner+D_dependents+D_PhoneService+D_PaperlessBilling+MonthlyCharges, data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(model_2)

model_3 = glm(D_Churn ~ SeniorCitizen+D_Partner+D_dependents+D_PhoneService+D_PaperlessBilling+MonthlyCharges, data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(model_3)

model_4 = glm(D_Churn ~ SeniorCitizen+D_Partner+D_dependents+D_PaperlessBilling+MonthlyCharges+TotalCharges, data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(model_4)

model_5 = glm(Churn ~ SeniorCitizen+D_dependents+D_PaperlessBilling+MonthlyCharges+TotalCharges, data = train, family = "binomial")
summary(model_5)

# Predict
predict1 <- predict(model_5, test, type = "response")
summary(predict1)
predict1
confusionMatrix(predict1,data$Churn)
```

I have made this logistic regression model, and i am not able to get to the end results of it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).